# How to control API4 permissions for CRUD operations?

Tags: api, acl

How do I control permissions for [API4](https://github.com/civicrm/api4) calls?

Answer (score 5):

## Events

The [API kernel](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/Civi/API/Kernel.php) broadcasts an [authorise event](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/Civi/API/Event/AuthorizeEvent.php#L28).

### Core permission check listener

The [main API permission check subscriber](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/Civi/API/Subscriber/PermissionCheck.php#L56) will respond to the event by:

```
$apiRequest = $event->getApiRequest();   
if ($apiRequest['version'] < 4) { /* blah */ }
elseif ($apiRequest['version'] == 4) {      
  if (!$apiRequest->getCheckPermissions()) {
    $event->authorize();                    
    $event->stopPropagation();              
  }                                         
}
```

### Adding your own listener

If the core logic doesn't meet your needs, it is possible to get the [symfony event dispatcher service](http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.html) and add either a listener (for single events) or a subscriber (for multiple events).

For example, to add a subscriber:

```
$subscriber = new MySubscriberClass();            
\Civi::service('dispatcher')->addSubscriber($subscriber);
```

When your listener/subscriber is called, then call the `$event->getApiRequest()` to find out the parameters you are being asked to authorise. If the event should be authorised then call `$event->authorize()`.

## SQL clauses

For actions based on `get()`,
the [selectQuery->getAclClause() method](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/Civi/API/SelectQuery.php) will call `$baoName::getSelectWhereClause($tableAlias)` to add a where clause.

It doesn't seem possible currently to apply differing ACL logic depending on the action with this method.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for documenting this. One caveat, the api4 is currently unstable and by the time it's released this information may be out-of-date.

Comment: @Coleman it's 5 years later, but I think this answer is still ok, right?

Comment: @artfulrobot Yes there's also a `permissions()` function you can put in the api4 entity file, to control gatekeeper permissions. Otherwise the BAO generally handles permissions.

Comment: @Coleman thanks for update. I guess the event method is useful primarily when wanting to alter core API permissions.